# Import CSV/Excel data into MYSQL database and remove duplicate using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter, csv

Today i came across a functionality where i need to i**mport the CSV/Excel file in to MYSQL database via codeigniter.** There is a special requirement from client where he can **upload the CSV/Excel file** in file upload field in **HTML form** and all data from CSV/Excel must **import into MYSQL** database table through PHP and remove the duplicates rows of data.But I faced some problems here.

**My problems is:**

1. when the user upload the csv file,its enter into the MYSQL database,but it have duplicates data of about 3-4 row.
2. the data in csv file is about 8000 rows but the data insert in MYSQL db is only about 5000(included the duplicates data)
3. this error occur when the file stop import the data

   [importcsv_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REID5.png)

This is my model

```
<?php
class Upload_services extends CI_Model{
   function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
  }
   function upload_sampledata_csv(){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
              $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
                while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE){
                    //check whether there are duplicate rows of data in database
                    $prevQuery = array(
                                    'articleno'=> $line[0] ,
                                    'product_description' => $line[1] ,
                                    'cust_name' => $line[2] ,
                                    'size' => $line[3] ,
                                    'colour' => $line[4],
                                    'process_description' => $line[5],
                                    'output' => $line[6],
                                    'material_part' => $line[7],
                                    'printingOutput' => $line[8]
                                    );

                    $q=$this->db->select('sindi_productprocess_temp', $prevQuery)
                            ->where('articleno',$line[0],
                                    'product_description', $line[1] ,
                                    'cust_name' , $line[2] ,
                                    'size', $line[3] ,
                                    'colour' , $line[4],
                                    'process_description' , $line[5],
                                    'output', $line[6],
                                    'material_part', $line[7],
                                    'printingOutput', $line[8]);

                $prevResult = $this -> db->query($q);

                if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
                    //update process data

                    $data = array(
                                'articleno' => $line[0] ,
                                    'product_description' => $line[1] ,
                                    'cust_name' => $line[2] ,
                                    'size' => $line[3] ,
                                    'colour' => $line[4],
                                    'process_description' => $line[5],
                                    'output' => $line[6],
                                    'material_part' => $line[7],
                                    'printingOutput' => $line[8]
                                );


                    $this->db->set
                    (
                                    'articleno',$line[0],
                                    'product_description', $line[1] ,
                                    'cust_name' , $line[2] ,
                                    'size', $line[3] ,
                                    'colour' , $line[4],
                                    'process_description' , $line[5],
                                    'output', $line[6],
                                    'material_part', $line[7],
                                    'printingOutput', $line[8]
                    );

                    $this->db-where('articleno',$line[0],
                                    'product_description', $line[1] ,
                                    'cust_name' , $line[2] ,
                                    'size', $line[3] ,
                                    'colour' , $line[4],
                                    'process_description' , $line[5],
                                    'output', $line[6],
                                    'material_part', $line[7],
                                    'printingOutput', $line[8]
                                     ); 

                    $this->db->update('sindi_productprocess_temp');


                }else{
                for($i = 0, $j = count($line); $i < $j; $i++){  
                      $data = array('articleno' => $line[0] ,
                                    'product_description' => $line[1] ,
                                    'cust_name' => $line[2] ,
                                    'size' => $line[3] ,
                                    'colour' => $line[4],
                                    'process_description' => $line[5],
                                    'output' => $line[6],
                                    'material_part' => $line[7],
                                    'printingOutput' => $line[8]
                                     );

            $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('sindi_productprocess_temp', $data);
                }
                 $i++;
            }
}
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");

}
}
function get_car_features_info(){
     $get_cardetails=$this->db->query("select * from sindi_productprocess_temp");
      return $get_cardetails;
}
}
?>
```

This is my controller

```
function processupload(){
        $this->load->model('upload_services');
        $data['result']=$this->upload_services->upload_sampledata_csv();
        $data['query']=$this-> upload_services->get_car_features_info();
        $this->load->view(' Upload_csv ',$data);
    }
```

And this is my view

```
<form action="{$path}pro/processupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td> Choose your file: </td>
              <td><input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile" id="userfile" align="center"/></td>
              <td><div class="modal-footer">
                    <td colspan="2" ><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Import"></td>
                  </div>
             </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Can anybody please help me on this??
Thank you.

Comment: Try printing out the array which you are passing to db. you are passing an object as error shows.
You can upload all the code including CSV files and Schemai cna try it on my machine

Comment: hi@usman ikram,here the link of my php file and my template                      https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNOE5BanljVndtT2M/view?usp=sharing
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNR0JqLS14MUtiY28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @usmanikram and this link is for my model and sample CSV file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNT2g3QVhJWU52clk/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNbmNERUk0WElLSXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide me database schema also

Comment: this is the database schema https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNb0pQcWVDNlJQUEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: fixed posting the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three mistakes:

1. You are passing multiple params to WHERE, you was passing it wrong
2. When we use SELECT and WHERE use use `get()` instead of `query()`, we use query when we write complete custom query.
3. you were using `for($i = 0, $j = count($line); $i < $j; $i++)` in else condition which is adding duplicate records

I also added two comments:

1. To remove header from your CSV (as in you code loop first iteration is checking headers only)
2. Instead of indexed array it better to use associative array

Below is the working complete code of your model:

```
    <?php
class Upload_services extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function upload_sampledata_csv()
    {

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");

            //fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",");// to remove header from CSV

            /*** If you want associated Array *****/

            /*
            $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
            $keys = array_shift($csv);
            //To turn all the rows into a nice associative array you could then apply:

            foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
                $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
            }
            */


            while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE)
            {


                //check whether there are duplicate rows of data in database
                $prevQuery = array(
                    'articleno'=> $line[0] ,
                    'product_description' => $line[1] ,
                    'cust_name' => $line[2] ,
                    'size' => $line[3] ,
                    'colour' => $line[4],
                    'process_description' => $line[5],
                    'output' => $line[6],
                    'material_part' => $line[7],
                    'printingOutput' => $line[8]

                );
                $where = array('articleno' => $line[0],
                              'product_description' => $line[1] ,
                              'cust_name'  => $line[2] ,
                              'size' => $line[3] ,
                              'colour'  => $line[4],
                              'process_description'  => $line[5],
                              'output' => $line[6],
                              'material_part' => $line[7],
                              'printingOutput' => $line[8]);


                $q = $this->db->select("*")
                            ->where($where)
                            ->from('sindi_productprocess_temp');



                $prevResult = $this->db->get();



                if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
                    //update process data

                    $data = array(
                        'articleno' => $line[0] ,
                        'product_description' => $line[1] ,
                        'cust_name' => $line[2] ,
                        'size' => $line[3] ,
                        'colour' => $line[4],
                        'process_description' => $line[5],
                        'output' => $line[6],
                        'material_part' => $line[7],
                        'printingOutput' => $line[8]

                    );


                    $this->db->set
                    (
                        'articleno',$line[0],
                        'product_description', $line[1] ,
                        'cust_name' , $line[2] ,
                        'size', $line[3] ,
                        'colour' , $line[4],
                        'process_description' , $line[5],
                        'output', $line[6],
                        'material_part', $line[7],
                        'printingOutput', $line[8]
                    );

                    $this->db-where
                    (
                        'articleno',$line[0],
                        'product_description', $line[1] ,
                        'cust_name' , $line[2] ,
                        'size', $line[3] ,
                        'colour' , $line[4],
                        'process_description' , $line[5],
                        'output', $line[6],
                        'material_part', $line[7],
                        'printingOutput', $line[8]
                    );

                    $this->db->update('sindi_productprocess_temp');


                }else{

                        $data = array(
                            'articleno' => $line[0] ,
                            'product_description' => $line[1] ,
                            'cust_name' => $line[2] ,
                            'size' => $line[3] ,
                            'colour' => $line[4],
                            'process_description' => $line[5],
                            'output' => $line[6],
                            'material_part' => $line[7],
                            'printingOutput' => $line[8]

                        );

                        $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('sindi_productprocess_temp', $data);

                }
            }
            fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");


        }
    }
    function get_car_features_info()
    {
        $get_cardetails=$this->db->query("select * from sindi_productprocess_temp");
        return $get_cardetails;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if i use  foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
                $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
            }
            ,do i need to  while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE) also??

Comment: No then you can foreach($csv as $line) instead of 
while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE) but then you have to change your whole code where you are accessing $line array

Comment: now i get this error  of array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: and also a database error of Column 'articleno' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `sindi_productprocess_temp` (`articleno`, `oldarticle`, `product_description`, `pro_type`, `cust_group`, `size`, `colour`, `output`, `process_description`, `material_part`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Comment: @Dn91 working fine on my end. You please use the whole code which i added in the answer, then please let me know what issue you are facing

Comment: I try the whole code ,there are no error now,but it insert a duplicate of about 9 rows for each data,plus it take up a bit longer to fully import all the data.where did i did wrong??

Comment: this link is for the CSV file after i finish import it to database ,it shows duplicate data https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNby1Tb0d3Y2lUQ3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you were using for($i = 0, $j = count($line); $i < $j; $i++) in else condition which is adding duplicate records, i have updated the code please try new code

Comment: its working now,my csv file is really huge,is it possible for me to finish import it to db with the shortest time? I had google about how to do it and found that some say use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ,but I don't understand how it work..

Comment: It will be always slow because for every record you are checking if it already exists into db or not.

Comment: Can we check duplication using 'articleno' only instead of checking all the fields?

Comment: great idea...one more question,if i want to update the existing data,can i change it update coding

Comment: Please mark this issue resolved and post a new question for optimization incuding this updated code

Comment: really thanks for your big help...appreciate it a lot

Comment: Always welcome, please add the link of new question here, i can update the code for optimization

Comment: @Dn91 You posted a new question?

Comment: here the link of my new question about update the data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787123/how-to-update-the-data-being-import-from-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :-

[Excel/CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeMBp.png)

Controller File Function

```
function import_flat(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
        while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('flat', array('name' => $line[0] ,'wingid' => $line[1]));
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            //update process data
            $data = array('name' => $line[0] ,'wingid' => $line[1]);
            $this->db->where('wingid', $line[1]);
            $this->db->where('name', $line[0]);
            $this->db->update('flat', $data);
            echo "Data update";
        }
        else
        {
            for($i = 1; $i < count($line); $i++)
            {  
                $data = array('name' => $line[0] ,'wingid' => $line[1]);
                print_r($data);
                print_r(count($line));
                $data['flats']=$this->db->insert('flat', $data);
            }
            $i++;
        }       
    }
    fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
    }
}
```

View File

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Flat/flats/importflat', array('method' => 'post')); ?>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Excel File For Flat</label>
          <br>
          <span class="btn btn-primary fileinput-button">
               <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
          <span>Add file</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" required>
          </span>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="mb-sm btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

[Database table for flat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06zI5.png)