# How to update the data being import from CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I have create a php function to import the CSV/Excel file in to MYSQL database via CodeIgniter.

1. It will check whether there are duplicate rows of data in database,if yet,it will update the data, else it will insert the data 
   my problem is when I update the CSV file and upload again,I get error of

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 759

this is my coding for import the CSV

```
class Upload_services extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function upload_sampledata_csv()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
            while(($line = fgetcsv($fp, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                //check whether there are duplicate rows of data in database
                $prevQuery = array(
                    'articleno'           => $line[0],
                    'oldarticle'          => $line[1],
                    'product_description' => $line[2],
                    'pro_type'            => $line[3],   
                    'cust_group'          => $line[4] ,
                    'size'                => $line[5] ,
                    'colour'              => $line[6],
                    'output'              => $line[7],
                    'process_description' => $line[8],
                    'material_part'       => $line[9]

                );
                $where = array(
                    'articleno'           => $line[0],
                    'process_description' => $line[8],
                    'material_part'       => $line[9]
                    );
                $q = $this->db->select("*")
                    ->where($where)
                    ->from('sindi_productprocess_temp');
                $prevResult = $this->db->get();

                if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
                    //update process data
                    $set =array('output'=>$line[7]);

                    $where = array(
                    'articleno'           => $line[0],                                  
                    'process_description' => $line[8],
                    'material_part'       => $line[9]
                    );

                $query = $this->db->get_where('sindi_productprocess_temp', array('output ='=>$line[7]))->result();

                }else{                
                    $data = array(
                        'articleno'           => $line[0],
                        'oldarticle'          => $line[1],
                        'product_description' => $line[2],
                        'pro_type'            => $line[3],   
                        'cust_group'          => $line[4] ,
                        'size'                => $line[5] ,
                        'colour'              => $line[6],
                        'output'              => $line[7],
                        'process_description' => $line[8],
                        'material_part'       => $line[9]
                    );

                    $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('sindi_productprocess_temp', $data);
                }
            }
            fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
        }
    }
}
```

this is my CSV file that not yet being update
[CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNby1Tb0d3Y2lUQ3M/view?usp=sharing)

I want to change output for AB02-OKE-01-09-Y0-001 from 500 to 200 for material_part=Top PVC Sheet-Left,and 300 for Top PVC Sheet-Right

when i change the code as below,it working but instead of updated the existing data,it insert the duplicate data

```
            if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
                //update process data

                $data = array(
                                'articleno'           => $line[0],
                                'oldarticle'          => $line[1],
                                'product_description' => $line[2],
                                'pro_type'            => $line[3],   
                                'cust_group'          => $line[4] ,
                                'size'                => $line[5] ,
                                'colour'              => $line[6],
                                'output'              => $line[7],
                                'process_description' => $line[8],
                                'material_part'       => $line[9]

                );

$set =array('output'=>$line[7]);

               $this->db->where = array(

                                'articleno'           => $line[0],
                                'oldarticle'          => $line[1],
                                'product_description' => $line[2],
                                'pro_type'            => $line[3],   
                                'cust_group'          => $line[4] ,
                                'size'                => $line[5] ,
                                'colour'              => $line[6],
                                'process_description' => $line[8],
                                'material_part'       => $line[9]
                );

            $this->db->update('sindi_productprocess_temp',$set);
```

Comment: As the error message states "pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given". You are passing an array to pathinfo as the first parameter, while the function expects it to be a string. Possibly, you haven't uploaded the code that produces this error.

Comment: @Dn91 please post your complete code

Comment: @usmanikram I have edited my post

Comment: @Dn91 Please add your updated CSV also

Comment: @usmanikram Done added the CSV file

Comment: you still haven't uploaded any code which calls pathinfo(), so it's hard to determine where or why that  error is occurring. The error message tells you the line number, so it shouldn't be hard to locate.

Comment: @Dn91 this code is working fine. not shwoing the warning

Comment: @usmanikram Its working now.

Comment: Is it still taking time to insert all records into database?

Comment: Yes it is......